# WebMatrix display authenticated user information

Tags: authentication, webmatrix

I would like to display the first and last name of the authenticated user.
I know there is the "CurrentUserName" property of the "WebSecurity" class that will retrieve the current authenticated user, but how can I retrieve its first and last name ?

I tried querying the users table but I have always an error message regarding the line the SQL query (starting var UserData ...): incorrect syntax near ','

In the code section:

```
@{

// Initialize general page variables
var authenticatedUser = "";
var authenticatedUserFirstName = "";
var authenticatedUserLastName = "";

if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    authenticatedUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
    var UserData = db.QuerySingle("SELECT (FirstName, LastName) FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", authenticatedUser);
    authenticatedUserFirstName = UserData.FirstName;
    authenticatedUserLastName = UserData.LastName;
    }
}
```

In the markup section:

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
                            <p>
                                Hello, <a class="username" href="~/Account/ChangePassword" title="Change password">@authenticatedUserFirstName @authenticatedUserLastName</a>!
                                <a href="~/Account/Logout">Logout</a>
                            </p>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets from around the FirstName, LastName fields in the SQL:

```
"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)"
```